# Не получается добавить значение в список

Tags: c#, list, xaml, xamarin.forms

Создаю приложение список дел. Приложение из двух страниц. Первая страница - сам список. Вторая страница - страница ввода значения. Но когда ввожу значение оно не появляется на главном экране.

//код с первой страницы

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private DotoListPage _todoListPage;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _todoListPage = new DotoListPage();
        BindingContext = _todoListPage;
        
    }
    

    private async void OnAddClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DotoListPage());
        
    }
}

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyTodoList.MainPage"
         Title="Заметки">

<StackLayout>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TodoList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="16,12" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Done}"
                                  Color="Gray"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Text}"
                               TextColor="Black"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button Text="+"
            TextColor="Black"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="End"
            Margin="15"
            Clicked="OnAddClicked">
    </Button>
</StackLayout>
```

//код со второй страницы

```
public partial class DotoListPage : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<TodoModel> _todoList;
    public ObservableCollection<TodoModel> TodoList
    {
        get { return _todoList; }
        set { _todoList = value; }
    }
    public DotoListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TodoList = new ObservableCollection<TodoModel>();
        TodoList.Add(new TodoModel
        {
            Text = "test",
            Done = false
        });//Тестовый текст, он выводится на первой странице

    }

    private async void OnSaveClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string result = placeholdetText.Text;
        AddItem(result);

    }

    

    private void AddItem(string text)
    {
        
        TodoList.Add(new TodoModel
        {
            Text = text,
            Done = false

        });
        
    }

}

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyTodoList.DotoListPage"
         Title="Добавление заметки">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Margin="15">
        
        <Entry x:Name="placeholdetText"
               
               Placeholder="Enter your text" 
               HeightRequest="50"/>
        <Grid>
            <Button Text="Save"
                    Clicked="OnSaveClicked"/>
        </Grid>
        <Label x:Name="labelText" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Код выглядит нормально. Проблема где-то в другом месте. Возможно вы показали не весь код или привели его не точно.

Comment: Я бы для начала попробовал заменить `placeholdetText.Text` на какую-то конкретную строку и посмотрел поменялось что-то или нет.

Comment: @aepot Добавил код с первой страницы

Comment: @CrazyElf Добавил Label и выводил туда данные веденые из Placeholdet, все работает корректно. Так же последовал вашему совету, поменял на обычную строку, все выводится корректно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await Navigation.PushAsync(new DotoListPage());` вы каждый раз при переходе на страницу создаете ее заново.

Надо так

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(_todoListPage);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)
Помогло